# What are the recommended specs for deploying IIS on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: windows, iis, web-server, hardware, windows-server-2019

So I've been looking around google and other sites for recommended specs for an IIS server, but I haven't found any information that matches my simple use case.

What would be the recommended specifications for IIS? We expect a load of maximum 50 people at the same time, could be 100

Edit: I think I should have shared more about what the app does, its a simple dashboard that uses .net framework, it connects to database and extracts data from it, sometimes thousands (from 1000 to 3000) of rows and presents them on a table. users can also insert into these tables. Its all made in one app, no microservices or web services.

Comment: It is rather difficult to define "simple", as a typical web app can require from a very low end cheap virtual machine to very high end deluxe physical machine, based on what that web app does exactly. That's why you found nothing and won't find much. [Capacity planning](https://kirshatrov.com/2018/10/21/capacity-planning-for-web-apps/) is not trivial so if your developers cannot do that, hire an experienced consultant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a lightly used IIS server, you should start with the recommended specs and then monitor performance and adjust if/where you see bottlenecks. Per the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/sys-reqs-19), you could start with the following:

One 64-bit 1.4 GHz processor core (I would start with 2)
2 GB RAM
50 GB disk space for OS and roles, with additional space for the site itself and for the paging file
RAID redundancy (not just striping) for the disks. It's common to use RAID 1 or better for the system disk and RAID 5 or better for the application data disks if those are separate.